# Hopf algebra structure on the ring of functions from an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras

A basic algebra statement confuses me. This is in Greenlees' *Equivariant Formal Group Laws and Complex Oriented Cohomology Theories*, p. 229 (in the journal).

If $k$ is a field, $A$ is an infinite discrete group, and $A^* = \operatorname{Hom}(A, \mathbb{T})$ is the Pontryagin dual, then $k^{A^*}$ is viewed via $\prod_{\alpha \in A^*} k$ as a complete topological Hopf algebra. I presume $A^*$ can be replaced by any infinite (topological) group.

The counit is probably the projection onto the identity factor. What is the comultiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like one can do the same as for finite groups via the group multiplication $k^{A^*} \to k^{A^* \times A^*} \cong k^{A^*} \widehat{\otimes} \ k^{A^*}$ but note that we need to apply the completed tensor product. (See Markus Hausmann's *Global group laws and equivariant bordism rings*, Section 2.1.)